# Django models, best way to save multiple values?

Tags: django, django-models

I need to save multiple values for the same foreign key. Let me give you an example:

```
class SaveMoz(models.Model):

    keyword = models.ForeignKey(KW)    
    m1 = ?    
    m2 = ?
    m3 = ? 
    m4 = ?
```

Each of these fields SHOULD represents analysed URL(via moz api) and I would like to store multiple values. Here is output I want to save:

```
[{u'pda': 53.2342343456775, u'upa': 23.45324234235234}, # These 2 would need to go to #m1
 {u'pda': 58.26193857945012, u'upa': 36.56733779379807}, # These 2 into #m2
 {u'pda': 66.15243480785065, u'upa': 35.377615927279244}, #m3
 {u'pda': 42.8651222137307, u'upa': 20.487826402597264}, #m4
]
```

I just gave 2 values(pda, upa) for each field as example, I will use 5(not all entered at the same time).

What is the best way to store those? MultiValueField ? Saving it as json ?
I will need to call these values later on to perform different calculations.

Comment: What about a 1:N or N:M [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) approach?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/

Comment: Both proposed solutions would then mean creating new classes for different values, correct? 

Since there will be 10 fields for each 5 sets of values, that would mean 50 new fields :) Or am I understanding this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), that will let you add extra context to the relationship.

```
class UrlData(models.Model):
    pda = models.FloatField()
    upa = models.FloatField()

class SaveMozData(models.Model):
    savemoz = models.ForeignKey('SaveMoz')
    kw = models.ForeignKey(KW)
    data = models.ManyToManyField(UrlData)

class SaveMoz(models.Model):
    keyword = models.ManyToManyField(KW,
                        through='SaveMozData',
                        through_fields=('savemoz','kw'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives error:

  File "/home/django/django_project/keywords/models.py", line 85, in SaveMozData
    savemoz = models.ForeignKey(SaveMoz)
NameError: name 'SaveMoz' is not defined

Comment: As SaveMoz is defined after SaveMozData, just quote the name (see updated edit).

Comment: Worked like a charm :) But now it returns: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'through_fields'

I can make the error go away if I change keyword = models.ForeignKey to ManyToManyField, is this correct solution ? Cheers

Comment: Yes, sorry it should be ManyToManyField

Answer (score 1):

Make m a seperate model/class that represents the data

```
class GoodNameForM(models.Model):
    moz = models.ForeignKey(SaveMoz)
    pda = DecimalField()
    upa = DecimalField()
```

Please be sure to give your fields names that represent them well

You can reference these on your `SaveMoz` via

```
save_moz_instance.goodnameform_set.all()
```